# How can I change the proofname to bold?

Tags: macros, bold, changes, logicproof

I changed the proofname using
`\renewcommand{\proofname}{Demonstração:}`
but I want the name "**Demonstração**" in a bold font. How Can I do it? Please!

Comment: You've tagged the question `logicproof`, but as far as I know, that package does not  define a command `\proofname`. Where does that command come from and what packages are you using? Post a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) if you can.

Comment: Are you using the `amsthm` package (which defines a macro called `\proofname`) and the `babel` package with either `portuguese` or `brazilian` as the language option? Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `amsthm` package the proof name style is `\itshape`. You can change it to `\bfseries` with the `\xpatchcmd` command in the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,regexpatch}

\usepackage[portuges]{babel}
\renewcommand{\proofname}{Demonstração}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\itshape}{\bfseries}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{.}{:}{}{} % After \proofname will be colon instead of dot
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Texto.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It worked only in LaTeX, but I need to use XelateX like compilation. Do you know how to use it there?

Comment: @Cícero Hitzschky It works with `xelatex` and `lualatex` for me.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, logicproof doesn't seem to have a \proofname command. Either way, you may just add a `\textbf{}` to your `\renewcommand` like this:

`\renewcommand{\proofname}{\textbf{Demonstração}:}`

Comment: This solution doesn't work in the next case: `\begin{proof}[Proof of Theorem 1]...\end{proof}` with `amsthm` package.

Answer (score 0):

If you see page 11 of `amsthm` manual you will see that it is recommended to write this code in the preamble of your document

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
\pushQED{\qed}%
\normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
\trivlist
\item\relax
{\itshape  %<- font shape
#1\@addpunct{.}}\hspace\labelsep\ignorespaces %<- includes punctuation code
}{%
\popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother
```

In the code, I have commented on the lines where `itshape` is used and the punctuation. Then, to obtain the output you want use something like in the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[portuges]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
\pushQED{\qed}%
\normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
\trivlist
\item\relax
{\bfseries % <- from itshape to bfseries
#1\@addpunct{:}}\hspace\labelsep\ignorespaces % change . for :
}{%
\popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
This proof is left as an exercise to the reader.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]